# Is it possible to run make with supressed warnings?

Tags: makefile

If i run `./configure && make` on any big open source project, for example Ruby, it will be thousands of compiler warnings displayed in the console. Is it possible to run it with warnings suppressed (and errors shown, if any)?

Comment: Do mean just *Make* warnings, or all warnings including those produced by things that Make calls (e.g. compilers)?

Comment: I've not compiled Ruby recently (if at all) but most of the software I do compile compiles without any warnings, usually even with the compiler options set to extremely fussy.

Comment: @Beta compiler warnings of course, C and C++ compilers. I have tried to `export` `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` with something like `-Wnone`, but it's not working - seems `make` internally changes this environment variables or supersedes them with something.

Comment: If the tool uses autoconf and automake, then CFLAGS & CXXFLAGS are reserved for your use.  HOWEVER, you *must* set them on the command line not the environment.  Make has a strict hierarchy of what settings override which and the environment is fairly low.  Running `make CFLAGS=-Wnone` will work.  Also note for any remotely  modern autoconf you can pass CFLAGS to the `configure` invocation and it will become the default: `./configure CFLAGS=-Wnone`.  However as said above, I've compiled LOTS of "big open source projects", and none of them show hardly any warnings, much less "thousands".

Comment: I think @MarkTehnick's solution is a pretty good one (*crude but effective*, which is highly underrated). But you seem to be solving the wrong problem: compiler warnings are your friends, and you should listen, at least to the ones pertaining to the parts of the code you're working on. To paraphrase Johannes Schaub, you can let the compiler tell you now, or ask the debugger to tell you later.

Comment: @Mad Unfortunately, if i execute `make CFLAGS='-Wnone'` it results in error "cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wnone"" (OSX 4.7, XCode 4.3)

Comment: @Eye, that means that your compiler doesn't support that flag.  Autoconf won't magically force all compilers to support the same options, and make is just passing whatever flags you tell it to :-).  IIRC, Apple doesn't like GCC due to GPL and they are trying to switch to clang.  So, you'll have to look at the documentation for your compiler to see what flags it supports and find the appropriate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `CFLAGS=-w CPPFLAGS=-w CXXFLAGS=-w LDFLAGS=-w` to your configure line.

Numbers!

```
$ tar -xzf ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-1.9.3-p125
$ { ./configure && make; } 2>&1 | wc -l
1197
$ cd ..
$ rm ruby-1.9.3-p125
$ tar -xzf ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-1.9.3-p125
$ { CFLAGS=-w CPPFLAGS=-w CXXFLAGS=-w LDFLAGS=-w ./configure && make;} 2>&1 |wc -l
989
$
```

There you have it.
Vanilla `configure && make`: **1197 lines**
Turning off warnings: **989 lines**
Savings: **17%**

Turning off warnings in no way inhibits display of errors, so you'll still know when things don't work.

<sup>Disabling warnings: 17% fewer lines.  Building Ruby repeatedly just to count the lines of output: priceless.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep for that. Use `make | grep -B 5 Error`.
That'll show line which contain phrase 'Error' and 5 lines before ;) I strongly suggest to put it in logfile before analyze so do `./configure && make > logfile`

Comment: You'd need `make 2>&1 | grep ...` to filter error messages written to `stderr`.  Or, `make >logfile 2>&1` if writing to a log file first.

Answer (score 1):

Convert all warnings to Errors.

```
-Werror
```

Set max errors to zero.

```
-fmax-errors=0
```

More...
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html